# R: RStudio: How to get silhouette plot working?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, r-daisy

Today I have realised that the `silhouette` plot in the `cluster` package doesn't display properly in `RStudio`. A Google search revealed that someone else had had a problem with this:

http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/3094-plotsnot-showing-up-in-r-studio

Being new to R, it was unclear to me whether the problem had been resolved in this thread! So my question is: is there a way to get the `silhouette` plot to display properly in `RStudio`?

Thanks for any help.

**Example script:**

```
library(cluster)
data(xclara)
km <- kmeans(xclara,3)
dissE <- daisy(xclara)
sk <- silhouette(km$cl, dissE)
plot(sk)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like the thread you reference was pretty explicit:  the `silhouette` package may have a bug wrt `png` output, and RStudio doesn't play nice with some other graphics formats.  So you need to specify, as Josh wrote, "The pdf(), quartz(), and windows() devices..."  when using RStudio.

Edit: so what you need to do is

```
pdf('my_nice_plot.pdf')
plot(sk)
dev.off()
```

Which writes your plot directly to the file.  You might try replacing the first line with `png('my_nice_plot.png')` and so on, as those should work as well.  But I doubt you'll get a clean plot in RStudio's graphics window until they upgrade their interface.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in the initial question, as I am new to `R` (or not very clever), I couldn't work out whether the thread had concluded with a solution. If there is code that I can add to the example script (see above) would you be so kind as to tell me what it is? Cheers.

Comment: How to use it with shiny? I am getting a blank plot when using it with shiny

Comment: @vipin8169 Sorry,  I've never used `shiny`

Comment: @vipin8169 I managed to get it work in shiny by first exporting the silhouette plot to a temp pdf file (`pdf(tempfile()) ... dev.off()`). I then convert this file into a temp png file with `animation::im.convert()` and finally rendering the png with `shiny::renderImage()` This is quite twisted but it works. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

This may be just an issue of visibility of the actual plot: try

```
library(cluster)
data(xclara)
km <- kmeans(xclara[1:100,],3)
dissE <- daisy(xclara[1:100,])
sk <- silhouette(km$cl, dissE)
plot(sk)
```